# Filter View on Empty Field

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus-formula

I have a Notes Domino application where I am trying to create a View which lists documents which are filtered on a particular field being empty.  I have the View created with the required fields and the field I am attempting to filter on I have set as a formula of @IsNull(FileCompletedDate) but the view is not returning anything.  What is the correct method to perform this please.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put

```
SELECT @IsNull(FileCompletedDate)
```

or

```
SELECT FileCompletedDate = ""
```

into **View Selection** formula.

You put your formula into *Column* formula. It defines the content of a column but has no effect on document selection.

Comment: Hermann Thanks.  This indeed gives me a view along the lines of what I need but as I scrolled down there was documents that DID have a value in the FileCompletedData field.  I tried both versions of your solution but the outcome was the same.

Comment: I had a typo in your field name (...Data instead of ...Date). I updated my answer. You probably just copied my code... `SELECT FileCompletedDate = ""` as a test if a value is available definitely works.

Comment: Hermann - Thanks yes.  This appears to work.  However, even with the type corrected there was something wrong and then found it was still showing documents with the FileCompletedDate populated and I found it was a column in view for Financial year that it doesn't like - for some reason when I remove the Financial year column it works fine!!!  Mystery!!

Comment: Always test a view in Notes Client and not just in Notes Designer. Maybe that's the reason for mystery...

Comment: Many thanks Knut.  Yes the years columns work fine when I amended the front end to allow me to select the view